# How to map paths in django 2.1 2018

Tags: python, django, path, django-urls

```
# My app path
urlpatterns = [
  path("", views.home, name="home"),
  path("show_category/<slug:category_slug>/", views.show_category, name="catalog_category"),
  path("<slug:product_slug>/", views.show_product, name="catalog_product")
]

def show_category(request, category_slug):
  context={
  "c" : get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug),
  "products" : c.product_set.all(),
  "page_title" : c.name,
  }
  template_name="catalog/category.html"
  return render(request, template_name, context)

# Project path
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("catalog.urls")),
    path("catalog/", include("catalog.urls")),
    path("cart/", include("cart.urls")),
]
```

I cant see any of my urls except my homepage and I'm new to django I see no documentation on it or anything in stackoverflow.. Any help would be great.
I dont want to do regex yet trying to learn how to do urls in both ways path and repath. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try to place function show_category in views.py file rather urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

Much of what you have isn't necessary, or is wrong. Fix everything you have into this. Notice my comments. I'm assuming your html templates are in the right spot so they render properly.

**ROOT PROJECT:**

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", views.home, name="home"),     # this makes yourwebsite.com/ the home page... Don't include yourwebsite.com/catalog/ twice, cause that's what you had.
    path("catalog/", include("catalog.urls")),
    path("cart/", include("cart.urls")),
]

# views.py
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'template_name.html')
```

**YOUR CATALOG APP:**

```
# urls.py

app_name = "catalog_app"
# all html templates linking to catalog/ must now use the following pattern: {% url 'catalog_app:name_argument' %}... examples follow...

urlpatterns = [
  path("", views.catalog_home, name="catalog_home"),    # goes website.com/catalog/, and must be referenced as {% url 'catalog_app:catalog_home' %} in html templates
  path("show_category/<slug:category_slug>/", views.show_category, name="show_category"),    # goes to website.com/catalog/show_category/category_slug/
  path("<slug:product_slug>/", views.show_product, name="catalog_product")
]


# views.py

from .models import YourCategoryClassModel

def show_category(request, category_slug):
    # the following .get() requires you to have an instance already created in the admin panel for it to work. Otherwise it won't work and you'll get errors.
    your_model_value = YourCategoryClassModel.objects.get(id=category_slug)
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'your_model_key': your_model_value})


# your_template.html

<p>{{ your_model_key.attribute_name }}</p>
<p>{{ your_model_key.whatever_you_called_them }}</p>
<p>{{ your_model_key.lowercaserelatedmodelname_set.any_method_or_attribute_for_that_model }}</p>
<!-- Or you can use the following -->
<p>{{ your_model_key.lowercaserelatedmodelname_set.all }}</p>
```

So for the template above, if you had a `Parent` class, and a `Child` class related to the parent by a ForeignKey field, the template would be like this:

```
<p>{{ your_model_key.child_set.all }}</p>
```